# ISTIO sidecar causes Java grpc client throws "UNAVAILABLE: upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers" under high concurrency load

Tags: java, grpc, istio, grpc-java, envoyproxy

I have two gRPC services and one will call another one through normal gRPC method(no stream on either side), I'm using istio as service mesh and have sidecar injected into kubernetes pod of both services.

The gRPC call works correctly under normal load, but under high concurrency load situations, gRPC client side keeps throwing the following exception:

```
<#bef7313d> i.g.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers
    at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:526)
    at i.g.s.ClientCalls$StreamObserverToCallListenerAdapter.onClose(ClientCalls.java:434)
    at i.g.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39)
    at i.g.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23)
    at i.g.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40)
    at i.g.i.CensusStatsModule$StatsClientInterceptor$1$1.onClose(CensusStatsModule.java:678)
    at i.g.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39)
    at i.g.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23)
    at i.g.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40)
    at i.g.i.CensusTracingModule$TracingClientInterceptor$1$1.onClose(CensusTracingModule.java:397)
    at i.g.i.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:459)
    at i.g.i.ClientCallImpl.access$300(ClientCallImpl.java:63)
    at i.g.i.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.close(ClientCallImpl.java:546)
    at i.g.i.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.access$600(ClientCallImpl.java:467)
    at i.g.i.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:584)
    at i.g.i.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
    at i.g.i.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123)
    at j.u.c.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at j.u.c.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Meanwhile, there's no exception on the server side, and there's no error on the `istio-proxy` container of client's pod neither. But if I disable istio sidecar injection so that those two service talk to each other directly, there's no such errors.

Could somebody kindly tell me why, and how to resolve this problem?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: That error message is not generated by grpc-java. So it is probably generated by istio.

Comment: @shizhz the error message is generated by the envoy (ingress gateway or in the sidecar in the service) as it cannot reach the upstream, can you post the manifests?

Comment: @rinormaloku, thanks for your response, I've found the reason and posted it as answer, hope it's helpful for other people facing the same problem :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally I found the reason, it's caused by the default `circuitBeakers` settings of envoy sidecar, by default the option `max_pending_requests` and `max_requests` is set to `1024`, and the default `connecTimeout` is `1s`, so under the high concurrency load situation when the server side has too many pending requests waiting to be served, the sidecar circuitBreaker will get involved and tell client side the server side upstream is `UNAVAILABLE`.

To fix this problem you need to apply a `DestinationRule` for the target service with reasonable `trafficPolicy` settings.